# Can't get Ajax data sent to my PHP function

Tags: 7, ajax

I recently took over an existing Drupal project and I tried to add a new PHP function (which works regularly) and link it with an Ajax query. There were already some in place that worked, and I wanted to add one that when you press a link, it sends the ID in the link to a PHP function which generates an info field. By copying the working code I got to this:

In my module, I added a `menu` hook referring to the PHP function in the module and the Ajax link:

```
$items['api/feedback'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'admin_user_feedback',
  'access arguments' => array('access feedback'),
  'access callback' => TRUE
);

return $items;
```

This is my Ajax code:

```
function getFeedback(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'api/feedback',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'id': id,
        },
        success: function(data){

            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){

            alert("error");
        },
    });
}
```

I know the function gets called on, but the console gives this error:

> POST http://localhost:8080/site/api/feedback 404 (Not Found)

The URL is correct, the other APIs with similar URLs do work, so somehow he doesn't recognise this API, I must have missed something. Does anybody know?

Comment: I should have asked this first before providing an answer: did you clear cache?

Comment: As side note, you don't need access arguments if you set the access callback to `TRUE`. The URL needs to be absolute, I think, in the JavaScript code, not relative like api/feedback.

Comment: Can you change router api/feedback to /api/feedback

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL again...  should it have `/site/` ?   I am guessing not, unless you have something going on it should be:   http://localhost:8080/api/feedback

```
url: '/api/feedback',
```

Comment: Yes, the folder is called 'site', the other APIs have exactly the same links (except for the end of course) and they are working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to attach `Drupal.settings.basePath` at the beginning of the url, it should be

```
url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'api/feedback',
```